# Send environment variables to Visual Studio app center using the CLI

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

How to I send environment variables for AppCenter builds using the CLI.

I want to send an environment variable such as "TENANT=customer1".

I am using a command similar to:

```
appcenter build queue -b master
```

I looked into the "--env" parameter but that seems to deal with the environment of things like API endpoints: https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-cli/blob/2c7fab9a3dc617c1d6b9b0dd1561d4baf0f50a7c/src/util/profile/environments.ts

Comment: Did you find a solution? I can't send env variables `appcenter build queue --app sample-android-app --branch master --env ENV1=val1 --token abxxx`
Error: ENV1 is not valid environment name

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but found a solution by doing this w/ an API call:

- do a `GET` on `https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/{owner}/{app}/branches/{branch}/config`
- copy paste the result, edit the `environmentVariables` section w/ the desired variables
- `PUT` the updated configuration back to `https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/{owner}/{app}/branches/{branch}/config`

more info about the API Calls can be found here: https://openapi.appcenter.ms/#/build/ and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/api-docs/